# What is the difference between publishing my web application in code or as a docker container?

Tags: azure, docker, azure-web-app-service

I currently manage service plans in Azure for my web applications, however I am considering options to set up microservices in Azure. When I want to try to create an app with a Docker container, it tells me that I should create a new service plan when I already have plans.

My question is What is the difference between uploading an app with a docker container and uploading it with code?

Comment: What is the version of your WebApp?

Comment: Which option yo uare using to deploy docker container ? [`Docker container registry`](https://i.imgur.com/LWmw8oK.png) or `Azure` => [`Azure container registry`](https://i.imgur.com/Q6NRL81.png)?

Comment: Deployment with Docker Container requires a Docker file with includes all the required dependencies for the App.
Whereas in regular upload, the infrastructure takes care of all the things required to build and run the app.

Comment: Add little bit of formatting while asking a question, highlight the information or any error you are receiving. Any code snippet, screenshot will be more helpful to understand the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your question I believe you are trying to create a new web app publishing a Docker container:

[image]

You already have web apps hosting code in Azure, on one or more existing web app plans.

You need a new app service plan if you publish using a Docker container because you can't mix the "code" web apps in a plan with "Docker" web apps.  They require separate app service plans.  That is the difference between uploading an app with a docker container and uploading it with code.